# Combine query result

Tags: python, django

I have written search view. Which works just fine. Now I want to change some logic.I want  if searching for "He" the results should display 10 results from language english and 10 results from language french. any suggestion? thanks

I am trying like this

```
languages = categories.language.all()
for language in languages:
    m = Movie.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q, language=language)[:10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
results = []
for language in categories.language.all():
    results.append(Movie.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q, language=language)[:10])
```